# Laravel Queue Job doesn't respect timeout

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, beanstalkd

I have this process setting.

```
php artisan queue:work beanstalkd --sleep=3 --tries=1 --timeout=0 --queue=medium,messages
```

I also have a job with the setting

```
public $timeout = 100000000;
```

But the job is stopped much before that with message `has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out` Which was run for the first time.

I also have this in php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: try to log and see til which part of the code your job executed

Comment: this job creates so many jobs and they might create other jobs, there is possibly no way to log that.

Comment: why this job create so many jobs? you should use console command rather creating a job which does it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Console

Things I want to execute from the command line (As you mentioned with your job creates more jobs). But the thing is, you could extract the business logic of it to a **command**.

[Example](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/imgubox/blob/master/app/Console/Commands/FetchUserFavs.php#L57): A console command with fires a command to fetch images from Imgur. The Class `FetchImages`  contains the actual business logic of fetching images.

#### Command

Class which contains the actual logic. You should also be able to call this command from your application with `app()->make(Command::class)->handle()`.

[Example](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/imgubox/blob/master/app/Jobs/FetchImages.php): Command mentioned in Example 1. Contains logic which does the actual API calls to Imgur and process returned data.

#### Jobs

Laravel 5.0 so `jobs` weren't a thing back then. But as I see it, Jobs are like commands but they are queued and can be dispatched. (As you may have seen in those examples, those commands implement your mentioned Interfaces `SelfHandling` and `ShouldBeQueued`).

---

I see changes in `Commands` and `Jobs` are quite difficult to understand.

EDIT:
From the Laravel Docs:

> The app/Commands directory has been renamed to app/Jobs. However, you are not required to move all of your commands to the new location, and you may continue using the make:command and handler:command Artisan commands to generate your classes.
>
> Likewise, the app/Handlers directory has been renamed to app/Listeners and now only contains event listeners. However, you are not required to move or rename your existing command and event handlers, and you may continue to use the handler:event command to generate event handlers.
>
> By providing backwards compatibility for the Laravel 5.0 folder structure, you may upgrade your applications to Laravel 5.1 and slowly upgrade your events and commands to their new locations when it is convenient for you or your team.